# How to prevent git from applying recorded changes during a git revert

Tags: git, git-revert, git-rerere

So I did a git revert and resolved the conflicts which turned out to not be the correct resolution. Now the next time I do a git revert, to get to a stage where conflicts are still unresolved, git already applied previous resolution.

To summarize:

- `git revert SHA`
- resolve conflicts
- `git add files-with-conflicts`
- `git revert --continue`
- Turns out git revert wasn't good during testing.
- `git reset --hard HEAD~`
- `git revert SHA` # In an effort to resolve the conflicts again the right way. But I can't because git has applied my previous resolutions. I'm confused!

How do i make a **fresh** git revert such that I can resolve conflicts again the right way?

Comment: Hard reset coupled with force push will help you, just cut off that bad-revert commit and start again. Be careful with `--hard` option - it removes all of the commits that were between current HEAD and that you are going to reset.

Comment: that's what i did. sorry if that wasn't clear. after git revert and resolving the commit. i did a `git reset --hard HEAD~` and then did a git revert again. git applied the conflict resolution  apparently because it recorded the change somewhere?

Comment: Revert just rolls back exactly those changes of the commit being reverted, and creates new commit with that reverting. Special case - reverting merge-commits, here you should point out mainline - branch which commits should be preserved. Can't reproduce your problem right now.

Comment: You can try to revert with `-n` option, it does revert, but doesn't do commits - you will be able to checkout changes manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the rerere database enabled. You have to remove the incorrect resolutions from the database.

As a first step, throw away the incorrectly reused resolution and start over:

```
git reset --hard
git revert SHA
```

At this point, the incorrect resolutions are applied again. Let's fix that. First, remove the  incorrect resolutions from the rerere database. You must do this per file:

```
git rerere forget name/of/file
```

Next, you resurrect the merge conflict and conflict markers:

```
git checkout --merge name/of/file
```

At this point, you can resolve the conflict in the correct way. Repeat for each file that has an incorrectly resolved conflict.

After you have fixed all incorrect resolutions, complete the commit as usual. The corrected resolutions will be recorded in the rerere database.